# Dynamically memory allocation within a function does not work, but no error occured

Tags: c, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to allocate memory for a array of chars. I wrote a function therefore, which return values tells me, that everything works fine, if I check it.
But when i try to write in the array a segmentation error occurs.
If i allocate the memory whitout the function (the commented area of the sourcode), everything seems to work fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ENWIK8 100000000
#define FILEPATH_INPUT "enwik8"
#define FILEPATH_OUTPUT "ergebnis/enwik8"

int array_alloc(char* array, int size);
int array_fill(FILE* file, char* path, char* array);

int main()
{

    FILE* enwik8_file;
    char *text_original;
    array_alloc(text_original, ENWIK8);

//THIS CODE WOULD WORK BUT NOT THE FUNCTION WITH SAME CODE
//   text_original = calloc(ENWIK8,sizeof(char));
//        if(text_original == NULL)
//        {
//            perror("Allocating array not possible!");
//            return -1;
//
//        }

    //Leads to: segmentation fault, if the function is used 
    //instead of the code above
    text_original[1000000] = 'a';
    return 0;
}



int array_alloc(char* array, int size)
{

    array = (char*)calloc(size,sizeof(char));
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        perror("Allocating array not possible!");
        return -1;

    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `array` is a local variable. Return the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `array_alloc`, you're assigning to a local variable:

```
array = (char*)calloc(size,sizeof(char));
```

Any changes to `array` are only visible here and not reflected in the calling function.  As a result, `text_original` is still uninitialized after `array_alloc` returns.  You then read and dereference that invalid pointer which invokes undefined behavior, which in this case causes your program to crash.

You need to change the function to accept a pointer to a pointer and pass the address of `text_original` from `main`.  So change the function to this:

```
int array_alloc(char **array, int size)
{
    *array = calloc(size, 1);
    if (*array == NULL)
    {
        perror("Allocating array not possible!");
        return -1;   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
array_alloc(&text_original, ENWIK8);
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thank you a lot!! .

Comment: @PhoenixTheCat Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: A few corrections to your answer: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 in C, and you should never ever cast the result of `malloc` or `calloc`, as doing that will only hide bugs.